# I am looking for an older font

Tags: fonts

Now I have and use the font **Isonormal Monospaced** from Robert Kirchner created in 1993. This font is great for code editing and I love it, but it does not contain all the characters for my language. So I'm looking for the professional version of this font **FF Isonorm Monospaced Pro**, but without success. All URL references to this font are not working (for example https://fontspy.com/fonts/ff-isonorm-monospaced-pro.font). 
Where could I find it?

Comment: I found some isonorm fonts at http://fontsgeek.com but not Pro.

Comment: How about this site? https://fonts.gr/fonts/en/cat/4/new/fresh/family/592/font/3217

Comment: Is a font from 1993 really old? I mean Helvetica is from 1957 and Century Schoolbook 1918 (Century being released in 1900)

Comment: In terms of digital fonts, then yes it's old. In terms of typeface design it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix "FF" means it was made by [FontFont](https://www.fontfont.com). I don't see it in their currect catalog ([this link](https://fontsinuse.com/typefaces/2476/ff-isonorm) says it's no loger for sale), but perhaps you can write to them and ask?

Otherwise there are several other [Isonorm versions](http://www.myfonts.com/search/isonorm/?refby=pixilate), one of which may fit the bill

Answer (score 0):

http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Isonorm-Monospaced-Regular
Might be it works.
This is not pro version but very much near to your requirements.